# display checkbox of checkboxlist jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a checkboxlist with around 40 items. I want to display only its first 20 items and rest will be `visible = false`. This checkboxlist is populated through database. Below is the code I am using but its not working:

```js
$(function() {
    var ctr = document.getElementById("chkTopCompanies");
    ctr.style.display = "none";
    var options = ctr.getElementsByTagName('label');
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        ctr.childNodes[i].display = 'block';
    }
})
```

None of the answers helped. This is the source generated for the Checkboxlist

```html
<table id="chkTopCompanies" style="color:#004080;font-weight:bold;margin-top: 10px; border-spacing: 20px 0;
                            font-size: small; margin-bottom: 10px; width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td><input id="chkTopCompanies_0" type="checkbox" name="chkTopCompanies$0" value="Accenture" /><label for="chkTopCompanies_0">Accenture</label></td>
        <td><input id="chkTopCompanies_1" type="checkbox" name="chkTopCompanies$1" value="Refbro consultancy limi" /><label for="chkTopCompanies_1">Refbro consultancy limi</label></td>
        <td><input id="chkTopCompanies_2" type="checkbox" name="chkTopCompanies$2" value="TCS" /><label for="chkTopCompanies_2">TCS</label></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have not copied only first 3 records for sample

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use `:gt()` selector and hide them easily.
Play with number inside `gt()` and hide the elements with an index number higher than a specified number. The index numbers start at 0:

```js
$("#chkTopCompanies td:gt(2)").hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="chkTopCompanies" style="color:#004080;font-weight:bold;margin-top: 10px; border-spacing: 20px 0;
                            font-size: small; margin-bottom: 10px; width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td><input id="chkTopCompanies_0" type="checkbox" name="chkTopCompanies$0" value="Accenture" /><label for="chkTopCompanies_0">Accenture</label></td>
        <td><input id="chkTopCompanies_1" type="checkbox" name="chkTopCompanies$1" value="Refbro consultancy limi" /><label for="chkTopCompanies_1">Refbro consultancy limi</label></td>
        <td><input id="chkTopCompanies_2" type="checkbox" name="chkTopCompanies$2" value="TCS" /><label for="chkTopCompanies_2">TCS</label></td>
        <td><input id="chkTopCompanies_2" type="checkbox" name="chkTopCompanies$2" value="TCS" /><label for="chkTopCompanies_2">Another</label></td>
        <td><input id="chkTopCompanies_2" type="checkbox" name="chkTopCompanies$2" value="TCS" /><label for="chkTopCompanies_2">Another 2</label></td>
        <td><input id="chkTopCompanies_2" type="checkbox" name="chkTopCompanies$2" value="TCS" /><label for="chkTopCompanies_2">Another 3</label></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I have added the html generated in questions. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

If you set a parent display to 'none', all of the children will be hidden as well, even if you specify their display to 'block'.

You might want to have a loop like this

```
for(var i = 19; i < 40; i++){
    ctr.childNodes[i].display = 'none';
}
```

So that the last 20 children will be hidden.

Comment: Yes you are correct it is, so is there any way I can set the last 20 items to invisible without setting the parent to display none

Comment: Check the updated answer, you can loop only the last children

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could use CSS for that

```
/* assuming that there are only checkboxes in  #chkTopCompanier */

#chkTopCompanies input:nth-of-type(n+20) {
   display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. I have shown the 1st 2 checkboxes and hide the rest.You can change the number as you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#chkTopCompanies td:gt(1)").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="chkTopCompanies" style="color:#004080;font-weight:bold;margin-top: 10px; border-spacing: 20px 0;
                            font-size: small; margin-bottom: 10px; width: 100%;">
 <tr>
  <td><input id="chkTopCompanies_0" type="checkbox" name="chkTopCompanies$0" value="Accenture" /><label for="chkTopCompanies_0">Accenture</label></td><td><input id="chkTopCompanies_1" type="checkbox" name="chkTopCompanies$1" value="Refbro consultancy limi" /><label for="chkTopCompanies_1">Refbro consultancy limi</label></td><td><input id="chkTopCompanies_2" type="checkbox" name="chkTopCompanies$2" value="TCS" /><label for="chkTopCompanies_2">TCS</label></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Anurag How can be this answer accepted? Is a copy paste of my answer......

Comment: @SilverSurfer: i have answered based on the HTML he had provided before you even edited your answer

Comment: Is not a good practice answer exactly the same. Before do it you should check the current answers.

Comment: @SilverSurfer I haven't checked your updated answer at that time.Will do that from now on. Sorry for that :)

Comment: Thanks, there is no problem. Good morning.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Angular Js (if possible for you)

```
   <ul>
    <li ng-repeat=" opt in options |limitTo:20 ">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="opt ">
    </li>
   </ul>
```

limitTo filetr can be dynamic , set a model in dropdown with  value like 10,15,20,30.... and use the model in limitTo filter and you all set